# flutter web on GitHub Pages not showing content

Tags: html, flutter, github-pages, flutter-web

I am trying to release my existing flutter project on the web (it already is working on iOS and android).

According to this great article:
[How to embed your Flutter app in WordPress](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-embed-your-flutter-app-in-wordpress-cd67e09fa29b)

I got to the point where I copied the build/web folder to my repository and pushed to master.
I ensured everything exist in the repository.

**yet NOTHING APPEARS on** https://username.github.io/app_folder

Just a blank page :(

Answer (score 19):

Found the problem in:
`repository_folder/app_folder/index.html`

When I deleted the following line, everything worked:

```html
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Instead of commenting out or deleting that line of code, what is the proper way of redirecting the route?

Comment: Hi @SawThinkarNayHtoo Did you found a proper solution to this?

Comment: @krishnakumarcn Here is a workaround. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69287 Same idea about deleting that line, but make changes in the .yml file of the .github folder so that you do not have to do it manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your
`<base href="/">` 
in the index.html file to

```
<base href="/<your_repository_name>/">
```

for example my repository name is crnb then  change `<base href="/">`  to   `<base href="/crnb/">`

This will surely work